# Haskell understanding flow

Tags: haskell

I'm new to haskell, I was trying to write a string split function

```
delim = '|'
splitStr::[Char]->[[Char]]->[[Char]]
splitStr list y                 
                | sL > 0 && sL < length(list) = splitStr (drop (sL+1) list) [subList]++y
                | otherwise = [subList]++y
                where 
                    subList = takeWhile (\x -> x /= delim) list 
                    sL = length(subList)

split s = splitStr s []
```

However, the above code always returns the String in reverse order

```
Main> split "foo|bar|java|python"
["python","java","bar","foo"]
```

changing from `y++[subList]` to `[subList]++y` still gives the same result. 
I know there maybe better ways to do it, but I want to know why the above is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
splitStr (drop (sL+1) list) [subList]++y
```

This is parsed as `(splitStr (drop (sL+1) list) [subList])++y`. What you wanted is probably `splitStr (drop (sL+1) list) ([subList]++y)`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is, additional to what sepp2k said, something about how to improve your code:

In your code you don't need an accumulator, since you can exploit the codes laziness. I rewrote your code like I would do it:

```
split :: Char -> String -> [String]
split delim "" = []
split delim s  = chunk : split delim rest where
 (chunk,_:rest) = break (==delim) s
```

How does it works? I split the string at the first char, that is equal to the delimiter. I return that part and call the function recursivly onto the rest of the list. This is very efficient, since Haskell won't evaluate the rest of the list until it's needed.

Comment: The problem was with precedence . Thanks for the alternative :)

Comment: @Rnet: In haskell, it's usually a bad idea to use tail-recursion with lists. Think of a list as a stream - the best algorithm that uses it should be able to compute only as much as needed and nothing more.

Comment: @Rnet: Good luck! What Haskell tutorial are you on? (And you can still upvote my answer, if you want to)